# Access webworks features from a phonegap app

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have an app for BB10 wrapped using Phonegap 2.9.

I want to access the webworks feature 'blackberry.ui.cover'. For a webworks app I just had to add `<feature id="blackberry.ui.cover" />`

Unfortunately this doesn't work for the Phonegap config.xml. How would I get access to this plugin? (And any other webworks plugin that doesn't have one for Cordova; there are lots...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question.

All of the original webworks plugins have been converted to new cordova plugins here - https://github.com/blackberry/cordova-blackberry-plugins.

To add the plugin you want to your project, simply run `./cordova/plugin add <path_to_plugin>`.

Comment: I ran across this git repository yesterday. I decided I couldn't be bothered adding all these plugins so I just switched the project to using purely Webworks and it works like a charm. No more Cordova/PhoneGap dependencies!! Thanks though!